# Can't use function return value in write context in line 51

Tags: php

Can't use function return value in write context

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: Welcome. Your `if` statement assigns a value, `=` should be `==`

Comment: several issues i see in your code:
1. you enclosed the sql query in  "()", at line 48.
2. line 51 your condition is not gonna work, use == instead of =. Now you are just trying to set the function return value to 0, instead of comparing it against the value 0.
3. For future copy/paste code snippets, it's pretty hard to get help while posting code snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

Line no 51 
Missing == compare sign

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
-------
}
```